# Get available locales for text to speech (TTS)

Tags: android, locale, text-to-speech

I'm working on a text-to-speech implementation of a flashcard program. Text in different languages should be read out. In order to do this properly the user has to select the language of the text to read (will be stored and used later without question).

Is there a possibility of getting the available TTS languages on an Android system? If not, is there a possibility of getting all availably locales on the system?

---

I guess, I got it: `getAvailableLocales()` and `tts.isLocaleAvailable(locale)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Find all available TTS Locale on the device using following function.

```
Locale.getAvailableLocales()
```

**Output of:** Arrays.toString(Locale.getAvailableLocales())

```
[ar, ar_EG, bg, bg_BG, ca, ca_ES, cs, cs_CZ, da, da_DK, de, de_AT, de_BE, de_CH, de_DE, de_LI, de_LU, el, el_CY, el_GR, en, en
_AU, en_BE, en_BW, en_BZ, en_CA, en_GB, en_HK, en_IE, en_IN, en_JM, en_MH, en_MT, en_NA, en_NZ, en_PH, en_PK, en_RH, en_SG, en_TT, en_US, en_US_POSIX,
 en_VI, en_ZA, en_ZW, es, es_AR, es_BO, es_CL, es_CO, es_CR, es_DO, es_EC, es_ES, es_GT, es_HN, es_MX, es_NI, es_PA, es_PE, es_PR, es_PY, es_SV, es_US
, es_UY, es_VE, et, et_EE, eu, eu_ES, fa, fa_IR, fi, fi_FI, fr, fr_BE, fr_CA, fr_CH, fr_FR, fr_LU, fr_MC, gl, gl_ES, hr, hr_HR, hu, hu_HU, in, in_ID,
is, is_IS, it, it_CH, it_IT, iw, iw_IL, ja, ja_JP, kk, kk_KZ, ko, ko_KR, lt, lt_LT, lv, lv_LV, mk, mk_MK, ms, ms_BN, ms_MY, nl, nl_BE, nl_NL, no, no_N
O, no_NO_NY, pl, pl_PL, pt, pt_BR, pt_PT, ro, ro_RO, ru, ru_RU, ru_UA, sh, sh_BA, sh_CS, sh_YU, sk, sk_SK, sl, sl_SI, sq, sq_AL, sr, sr_BA, sr_ME, sr_
RS, sv, sv_FI, sv_SE, th, th_TH, tr, tr_TR, uk, uk_UA, vi, vi_VN, zh, zh_CN, zh_HK, zh_HANS_SG, zh_HANT_MO, zh_MO, zh_TW]
```

Comment: According to the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getAvailableLocales%28%29 getAvailableLocales() is static, so there's no need to create a Locale object.  Using "Locale.getAvailableLocales()" is the appropriate way to use this method.

Comment: Are all the locales that are available supported by the tts ?

Comment: @Abhinav of course not. Why the OP accepted this as answer is beyond me.

Comment: Any idea how to force male voice instead of female voice? Using URL parameters?

Comment: `getAvailableLocales()` won't work before Lollipop. try `isLanguageAvailable()`

Answer (score 23):

Someone else has done the hard work, at http://kaviddiss.com/2012/08/12/android-text-to-speech-languages/

To save you time, here's their code extract

```
TextToSpeech tts = ...
// let's assume tts is already inited at this point:
Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
List<Locale> localeList = new ArrayList<Locale>();
for (Locale locale : locales) {
    int res = tts.isLanguageAvailable(locale);
    if (res == TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE) {
        localeList.add(locale);
    }
}
// at this point the localeList object will contain
// all available languages for Text to Speech
```

The results depend on which TTS engine has been selected. For instance, one of my phones includes both the Pico-TTS and Google-text-to-speech engines.

Q-Smart (Vietnamese Phone with Google TTS as selected engine)

```
D/SpeakRepeatedly( 3979): Engine Google Text-to-speech Engine:com.google.android.tts
D/SpeakRepeatedly( 3979): Engine Pico TTS:com.svox.pico
D/SpeakRepeatedly( 3979): German (Germany):German:de_DE
D/SpeakRepeatedly( 3979): English (United Kingdom):English:en_GB
D/SpeakRepeatedly( 3979): English (United States):English:en_US
D/SpeakRepeatedly( 3979): English (United States,Computer):English:en_US_POSIX
D/SpeakRepeatedly( 3979): Spanish (Spain):Spanish:es_ES
D/SpeakRepeatedly( 3979): French (France):French:fr_FR
D/SpeakRepeatedly( 3979): Italian (Italy):Italian:it_IT
D/SpeakRepeatedly( 3979): Portuguese (Brazil):Portuguese:pt_BR
D/SpeakRepeatedly( 3979): Portuguese (Portugal):Portuguese:pt_PT
```

And with Pico selected

```
D/SpeakRepeatedly( 4837): Engine Google Text-to-speech Engine:com.google.android.tts
D/SpeakRepeatedly( 4837): Engine Pico TTS:com.svox.pico
D/SpeakRepeatedly( 4837): German (Germany):German:de_DE
D/SpeakRepeatedly( 4837): English (United Kingdom):English:en_GB
D/SpeakRepeatedly( 4837): English (United States):English:en_US
D/SpeakRepeatedly( 4837): English (United States,Computer):English:en_US_POSIX
D/SpeakRepeatedly( 4837): Spanish (Spain):Spanish:es_ES
D/SpeakRepeatedly( 4837): French (France):French:fr_FR
D/SpeakRepeatedly( 4837): Italian (Italy):Italian:it_IT
```

Note:
Portuguese isn’t listed in the TTS Settings UI. When I select Portuguese programmatically in my app it speaks with a Portuguese accent! FWIW here's my code to select Portuguese (it accepts both Brazilian and Portuguese locales).

```
if (locale.getDisplayName().startsWith("Portuguese")) {
    Log.i(SPEAK_REPEATEDLY, "Setting Locale to: " + locale.toString());
    tts.setLanguage(locale);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: this will not work for all devices and all TTS engines as it doesn't match [`LANG_COUNTRY_VAR_AVAILABLE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE). You should use `res >= TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE`

Answer (score 17):

Since different TTS engines return different results for `isLanguageAvailable`, I found that the following solution works best on several common TTS engines.

Please also note that starting with Android Lollipop, there is a simple method in `TextToSpeech` called [`getAvailableLanguages`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#getAvailableLanguages()) that does that easily for you (if the device is running API 21 or later).

You need to call the following methods in the `onInit` method of your `OnInitListener` assigned to the `TextToSpeech` object.

```
ArrayList<Locale> languages;
TextToSpeech initTTS;

private void initSupportedLanguagesLollipop()
{
    Set<Locale> availableLocales = initTTS.getAvailableLanguages();
    for (Locale locale : availableLocales)
    {
        languages.add(locale);
    }
}

private void initSupportedLanguagesLegacy()
{
    Locale[] allLocales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
    for (Locale locale : allLocales)
    {
        try
        {
            int res = initTTS.isLanguageAvailable(locale);
            boolean hasVariant = (null != locale.getVariant() && locale.getVariant().length() > 0);
            boolean hasCountry = (null != locale.getCountry() && locale.getCountry().length() > 0);

            boolean isLocaleSupported = 
                    false == hasVariant && false == hasCountry && res == TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE ||
                    false == hasVariant && true == hasCountry && res == TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE ||
                    res == TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_VAR_AVAILABLE;

            Log.d(TAG, "TextToSpeech Engine isLanguageAvailable " + locale  + " (supported=" + isLocaleSupported + ",res=" + res + ", country=" + locale.getCountry() + ", variant=" + locale.getVariant() + ")");

            if (true == isLocaleSupported)
            {
                languages.add(locale);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error checking if language is available for TTS (locale=" + locale +"): " + ex.getClass().getSimpleName() + "-" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Android 5.0 (API level 21), `TextToSpeech.getAvailableLanguages` has been added to fetch a set of all locales supported by the TTS engine.

```
TextToSpeech tts;              // assume this is initialized
tts.getAvailableLanguages();   // returns a set of available locales
```

I have also noticed that the set of locales returned by `TextToSpeech.getAvailableLanguages` might not be a strict subset of `Locale.getAvailableLocales`, i.e. there might a locale supported by the TTS engine that isn't supported by the system.

Comment: what if a locale is supported by tts engine but the system doesnt support it. Will tt.setLanguage() work ?