# Certain locales not available in TTS--including Spanish

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

When I use this line to set Locale for Japanese it works just fine.

```
tts.setLanguage(Locale.JAPANESE);
```

When I substitute FRENCH, GERMAN, ITALIAN and CHINESE it also works.

When I substitute SPANISH, RUSSIAN or HINDI Eclipse tells me "SPANISH cannot be resolved or is not a field" [fill in for the other languages].

I am told Android does provide support for these languages, so how is it possible I do not find them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation the Locale object](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#lfields) has no constant for spanish defined. You can try to use this (not tested):

```
Locale locale = new Locale("es", "ES");
tts.setLanguage(locale);
```

But keep this note in mind (also from the Locale documentation):

> It is also a mistake to assume that all devices have the same locales
>   available. A device sold in the US will almost certainly support en_US
>   and es_US, but not necessarily any locales with the same language but
>   different countries (such as en_GB or es_ES), nor any locales for
>   other languages (such as de_DE). The opposite may well be true for a
>   device sold in Europe.

Comment: I used a bit of code witchery from this thread
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872702/get-available-locales-for-tts 

    Locale loc = new Locale("en");
    Log.i("-------------",Arrays.toString(loc.getAvailableLocales()));

to get a list of locales supported, and  es_ES is among them.  So, my problem may lie elsewhere.

Comment: So, I ended up using your suggestion after all, and it worked with all my locales.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Correction: works for everything except Chinese, which is supported according to the results of getAvailableLocales(), but does not in fact work.

Comment: Neither Locale("es", "ES") nor Locale("esp", "ESP") nor Locale("sp", "SP") nor Locale("spa", "MEX") e.t.c. These are not working with Locale function on Android target API 30 and below versions. I am hopeful about the future updates.