# TextoToSpeech in another language

Tags: android, android-studio, text-to-speech

I'm trying to do a TextoToSpeech program in Android Studio but I want it to get a word and say it in another language(portuguese) that is not listed when I hit CTRL+SPACE.

How do I set this new language?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872702/get-available-locales-for-tts

Answer (score 0):

Well, It's related to the **TTS Engine**, there is a lot of engines like the **Google TTS Engine**, You can change language to speak by using **setLanguage()** function. Lot of languages are supported like Canada, French, Chinese, Germany etc.,but if the 'portuguese' language does not appear so you can not add it using this engine, so i suggest you to change your engine, there are a lot of engines, try to use Ekho engine, or find what engine support the portuguese language!!

```
tts.setLanguage(Locale.CHINESE); // Chinese language
```

I hope it will help you, best regards