# Android TTS pronouns A and Z wrong

Tags: java, android, kotlin, text-to-speech

I am creating an app that will randomly generate character using ascii numbers and pronounce it with help of android TTS.

But When the character *A* and *Z* have some problems. A spell as *I* and Z as *c*.

```
  var ascInt: Int = randomAscii
  ascInt = ascInt.plus(97)
  val ascChar: Char = ascInt.toChar()
  s = ascChar.toString()
```

1. I put *.(dot)* but not solved the problem.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: what  locale  did you use for the TTS ? you can try different en locales like (UK, AU, etc).

Comment: @AngelKoh  I tried Locale.Us and Locale.UK . And It does nothing for me

Comment: you have to use  en_UK, en_AU, en_IN, etc. (note that you should check if the phone has that locale country or not also) refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872702/get-available-locales-for-text-to-speech-tts.

Comment: _c/zee_ would be correct for a US locale.